# Link ontologies from DBpedia to external ones with sameAS

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantics, dbpedia

Is there a way in SPARQL to automatically connect instances of one ontology in DBpedia and another in a different database.
For example

> http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Daphne_Gere
>   and http://dbpedia.org/page/Daphne_Gere

are similar and connect with the propriety `sameAs`, but I would like to be able to do it for all instances of the ontologies where they belong

> http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/wordnet_actor_109765278 and http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Actor

So for example the result will be a table that has all the instances from one class with their equivalent in the other class.

Comment: Note that `http://dbpedia.org/page/Daphne_Gere` is **not** the Daphne_Gere resource on DBpedia.  The resource is `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Daphne_Gere`.  When you put the latter in a web browser, you just get redirected to the former for a HTML presentation of the data about the resource.

Comment: DBpedia already has lots of this information.  Would a query to retrieve it be sufficient?

Comment: Duplicate on answers.semanticweb.com http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/29411/link-ontologies-from-dbpedia-to-external-ones-with-sameas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple query to DBpedia, which already contains (most of?) the links that you want?

```
select ?dbid ?yagoid where {
  ?dbid a dbpedia-owl:Actor ;
        owl:sameAs ?yagoid .
  filter strstarts( str(?yagoid), 'http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/' )
}
limit 100
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fdbid%20%3Fyagoid%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fdbid%20a%20dbpedia-owl%3AActor%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20owl%3AsameAs%20%3Fyagoid%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20strstarts%28%20str%28%3Fyagoid%29%2C%20%27http%3A%2F%2Fyago-knowledge.org%2Fresource%2F%27%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

```
dbid                                       yagoid
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Amy_Fisher     http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Amy_Fisher
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Angel_Dark     http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Angel_Dark
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anita_Mui      http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Anita_Mui
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Annabel_Chong  http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/Annabel_Chong
…                                          …
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if I want to do it between two other databases.. For example, YAGO producer: `http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/wordnet_producer_110480018` and `LinkedMDB producer http://data.linkedmdb.org/page/movie/producer`

Comment: Or even less, for example if I want to link DBpedia to LinkedMDB where URIs are not represented the same way (example, `http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/producer/10019`)

Comment: @Suvimo I'm not sure what you mean;  I don't see any owl:sameAs links in the LinkedMDB URL you posted.  Are you trying to retrieve owl:sameAs links, or are you trying to heuristically identify identical individuals?  If you're trying to identify identical individuals that aren't already connected by an owl:sameAs link, then you need to update your question with the heuristic you're trying to use.

Comment: @Suvimo I see that you posted (and deleted) an answer about two hours after mine.  It's essentially the same as what I posted, except that using `FILTER(contains(str(?entity2),"yago"))` tests for something slightly different than `filter strstarts( str(?yagoid), 'http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/' )`.  The strstarts test is 'cheaper' since it can fail more quickly, while the contains check will match anything that has yago in it, even if it's part of someone's name or something.  I think the contains check is probably a bit more robust.

Comment: first thanks for the continuous support
The problem that I see with your SPARQL, is that unless the name is specified in the URL, the query cannot detect it. For example, it will not detect this match in DBpedia `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Jet_Li` and linkedMDB `http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/producer/9712`
The query in the comment that I deleted does actually detect those as well, but I just dont see it to be based on the actual logic of "sameAs"..

Comment: The query in your deleted answer wouldn't detect `http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/producer/9712`.  It doesn't contain the string "yago", and you were using FILTER(contains(str(?entity2),"yago")).

Comment: Yes sir, but I would then simply replace yago by "linkedmdb". Yago was just an example really of linking the two ontologies, that's why i rather need a generic query that will work whenever there is a "sameAs" linkage, given the two ontologies of course!

Comment: In my example, you could just as easily replace `http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/` with `http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/`.  But if all you're looking for is owl:sameAs links, and you don't care about the prefixes of the URIs, why isn't `select ?x ?y { ?x owl:sameAs ?y }` enough?

Comment: wow man, I didnt realize your code was working, I thought what you did was just to compare the string after `/resource/` in both dbPedia and Yago, and if they are the same, you'd return that match. Thank you so much! I am grateful!